# How to use beanvalidation on external objects?

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

I'd like to use BeanValidation mechanisms like `@NotNull, @Size` etc on a big object. I only want to validate certain properties that I make use of.

The object comes from an external library, so I cannot add annotations to it's getters. Neither would I like to manually create my own object and make a deep copy of the project.

Is there any change I could use a BeanValidation framework on a class that I cannot change? Similar to:

```
class MyValidator {
    @NotNull
    static String getUsername(ExternalClass ext) {
         return ext.getUser();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered by mvb13, you can use the XML based configuration for this. If you're working with Hibernate Validator as your BV provider you also can leverage the [API for programmatic constraint declaration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-api):

```
HibernateValidatorConfiguration configuration = Validation
    .byProvider( HibernateValidator.class )
    .configure();

ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = configuration.createConstraintMapping();

constraintMapping
    .type( ExternalClass.class )
        .property( "someProperty", FIELD )
            .constraint( new NotNullDef() )
            .constraint( new SizeDef().min( 2 ).max( 14 ) )
    .type( AnotherExternalClass.class )
        .property( "anotherProperty", METHOD )
            .constraint( new NotNullDef() );

Validator validator = configuration.addMapping( constraintMapping )
    .buildValidatorFactory()
    .getValidator();
```

Answer (score 0):

Exists variant of using xml config to describe validation rules. This is how it is implemented in Hibernate https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-xmlconfiguration.html
In this case you don't need to change source code.